# How to transform this code into a function def()

Tags: python

How do I transform this into a function `def()`

```
detected_faces1 = face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + source_image_file_name1, detection_model='detection_03')
    source_image1_id = detected_faces1[0].face_id
    print('{} face(s) detected from image {}.'.format(len(detected_faces1), source_image_file_name1))
```

I tried doing this:

```
def detected_faces1():
    face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL, detection_model='detection_03')
    source_image1_id = detected_faces1[0].face_id
print('{} face(s) detected from image.'.format(len(detected_faces1)))
```

But I get an error:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `detected_faces1` is a function, you can't pass it directly to the `len` function, you should execute it and pass the result, like this `len(detected_faces1())`.

Also, your function will return None (the default), you need to `return xx` to return the result you want.

```py
def detected_faces1():
    return face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + source_image_file_name1, detection_model='detection_03')
    # source_image1_id = detected_faces1[0].face_id
     

print('{} face(s) detected from image {}.'.format(len(detected_faces1()), source_image_file_name1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two objects both named `detected_faces1` - one is a list and the other is a function.

Update it and it should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to **return detected_faces1** in the function in order to access it.

```
def detected_faces1():
    detected_faces1 = face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + source_image_file_name1, detection_model='detection_03')
    source_image1_id = detected_faces1[0].face_id
    return detected_faces1

print('{} face(s) detected from image {}.'.format(len(detected_faces1()), source_image_file_name1))
```

If you want to return multiple elements from a function you can use an **array** OR **dictionary**.

**Example array:**

```
def detected_faces1():
    detected_faces1 = face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + source_image_file_name1, detection_model='detection_03')
    source_image1_id = detected_faces1[0].face_id
    return [detected_faces1, source_image1_id]

data = detected_faces1()
```

`data[0]` will be **detected_faces1** and `data[1]` will be **source_image1_id**.

**Example dictionary:**

```
def detected_faces1():
    detected_faces1 = face_client.face.detect_with_url(IMAGE_BASE_URL + source_image_file_name1, detection_model='detection_03')
    source_image1_id = detected_faces1[0].face_id
    return {'faces': detected_faces1, 'source_image1_id': source_image1_id}
data = detected_faces1()
```

You can access the values using `data[key]` e.g `data['faces']`.